# Can I sort a generator function from within itself without creating another wrapper function, or sorting it outside?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, os.walk

I have a nicely working wrapper around `os.walk()` that maps deeply discovered files and dirs onto a subclass of `Path`:

class Find:

```
@staticmethod
def deep(path: Union[str, Path, 'WalkPath'], 
            sort_key=lambda p: str(p).lower()) -> ['WalkPath']:
    
    if Path(path).is_file(): 
        return [WalkPath(path)]
    
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(WalkPath(path)):
        
        dirs = sorted([WalkPath(root).joinpath(d) for d in dirs], key=sort_key)
        files = sorted([WalkPath(root).joinpath(f) for f in files], key=sort_key)
        
        yield WalkPath(root, dirs=dirs, files=files)
        yield from files
```

This works pretty well - I can iterate on the results, and on any of them, inspect the files or dirs contained within.

Unfortunately the result comes back rather unsorted. I know I can do this:

```
paths = sorted(Find.deep(root), key=lambda p: str(p).lower())
```

after the fact, or I could create a wrapper function:

```
@staticmethod      
def sorted_deep(path):
    yield from sorted(Find.deep(root), key=lambda p: str(p).lower())
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way I can handle that sorting directly in the main function? I tried looking into whether I could re-work it to fit a lambda expression, but couldn't get that to work with assigning dirs and files.

For completeness, here's the WalkPath object:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union

class WalkPath(Path):
    
    _flavour = type(Path())._flavour
    
    def __init__(self, *args, dirs: []=[], files: []=[]):
        """Initialize WalkPath object.

        Args:
            dirs (list):    Dirs provided by os.walk(), defauls to []
            files (list):   Files provided by os.walk(), defaults to []
        """
        
        super().__init__()
        
        self.dirs: [WalkPath] = list(map(WalkPath, dirs))
        self.files: [WalkPath] = list(map(WalkPath, files))
    
    def joinpath(self, path) -> 'WalkPath':
        joined = WalkPath(super().joinpath(path))
        self.__dict__ = joined.__dict__.copy()
        return joined
    
    @property
    def is_terminus(self) -> bool:
        return self.is_file() or not self.dirs
    
    @property
    def dirs_abs(self) -> ['WalkPath']:
        return [self.joinpath(d) for d in self.dirs]
    
    @property
    def files_abs(self) -> ['WalkPath']:
        return [self.joinpath(f) for f in self.files]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very concept of a sorted object involves comparing its elements to determine which are greater than others. A generator, by nature, only produces each of its elements one at a time. If you want to see elements yielded in a certain order, you should ideally write your generator's algorithm to produce the order you actually want. Otherwise, you'll have to exhaust it into a data structure and then sort that (obviously not ideal because it defeats the benefits of a generator).

As far as the specific generator you've written, my recommendation would be to consider the way it's producing its "rather unsorted" results - you're already sorting some loops within it, so I'd expect it to have some kind of order. Investigate exactly how you're getting that order and determine how it differs from the order you'd like to see, then adjust as necessary.

As far as the general question of forcing a generator into a different order than its algorithm produces, no, there's no way to do that without storing the entire result and then comparing the produced elements to each other, i.e., sorting.

Comment: That's a fair point. In this case, because it's based off of os.walk(), I don't think I have a lot of choice in the sorting matter, but I'll keep looking at it.